# Convert markdown image format to html

Tags: python, html, markdown

I am using the markdown2 library in python to convert markdown to html.

However, it does not support the common image formatting

> ```
> [![alt text][some link]][img src link]
> ```

which should convert to

```
<a href="some link" rel="alt text"><img src="img src link"/></a>
```

But I am mostly getting, from this and other markdown libraries

```
import markdown2
markdown2.markdown('[![hi][http://google.com]][http://example.com/png]')
u'<p>[![hi][http://google.com]][http://example.com/png]</p>\n'
```

What options do I have if I want to have images in my markdown files that are eventually converted to html.

Comment: Markdown usually supports inline HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Found it in [their source code](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2/blob/master/lib/markdown2.py#L1086), they have a slightly different format for images.