# How to find image with its source in python markdown2

Tags: python, markdown

I am trying to make a static site generator with Python. I coded most of it. But there is a problem.

When I add an image to a Markdown file (like this: `![Python](python.png)`) it embeds it to an HTML file. But when I process it and save the Markdown file's HTML to output folder, it should also move the used images to the same directory for proper displaying of image.

I don't want to move unnecessary images to the output directory.

- I am using `markdown2` for processing the Markdown files
- I am using jinja for templating the HTML files

solution i tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_images(html_path) :
    with open(html_path) as file :
        soup = bs(file.read(), "html.parser")
        images = []
        for img in soup.find_all("img"):
            img_url = img.attrs.get("src")
            if img_url:
                images.append(img_url)
    return images
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried using beatifulsoup but it takes an extra process for each page. I want to use markdown2 modules simplicity.

Comment: unless I'm missing something, BeautifulSoup has no place here. That's for _parsing_ HTML, not generating it. Please [edit] your question and tell us exactly how these pieces all fit together, as a [mre]. Show a directory structure, where your Markdown files live, where the images live, and  how you're using `markdown2` and Jinja.

Comment: BeautifulSoup may be involved because the OP is using it to extract image links from the generated HTML (rather than trying to parse image links directly from the Markdown). This is a fairly common pattern, but as other commenters have noted the OP hasn't provided any information about how they've tried to solve the problem.

Comment: I added my attempt. But still it takes an extra step.

Comment: My question is similiar to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827740/convert-markdown-image-format-to-html